# How to get JSON.loads() output in dictionary type but not string type using PYTHON

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests, python-responses

When I make use of **JSON.dump()** I am getting below JSON format

```
Dumps data"b'{\"AutomaticReadabilityIndex\":2.7999999999999994,\"AgeLevel\":[\" 11 to 12\"],\"Statement\":[\"Nice. Your grade is about six\"],\"SpacheScore\":1.877,\"GunningFogScore\":9.099999999999998,\"SmogIndex\":5.999999999999999}'"
```

When I make use of **JSON.loads()** I am getting below JSON format with bytes

```
loads data b'{"AutomaticReadabilityIndex":2.7999999999999994,"AgeLevel":[" 11 to 12"],"Statement":["Nice. Your grade is about six"],"SpacheScore":1.877,"GunningFogScore":9.099999999999998,"SmogIndex":5.999999999999999}'
```

My question is when I am using loads format the output has to be in **dictionary** type but I don't know why I am getting **string** type as my output. How to convert this JSON string into dictionary type.

```
Loads Data Type : type of loads <class 'str'>
```

When I trying to parse string type JSON directly I am getting below error

```
ERROR : Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Db.py", line 84, in <module>
print(par['GunningFogScore'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: you're dumping a `json` string not a python dict (you're dumping a dump...). Don't dump a string using `json`, just write it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre what does it mean "don't dump a string using json just write it" i'm struggling with the same error but dont get your comment :(

Comment: @soommy12 since you were able to dig up the question and you have the same problem, I made an answer then. Tell me if you understand better.

Answer (score 5):

I can reproduce your problem simply with:

```
import json

s = {"AutomaticReadabilityIndex":2.7999999999999994,"AgeLevel":[" 11 to 12"],"Statement":["Nice. Your grade is about six"],"SpacheScore":1.877,"GunningFogScore":9.099999999999998,"SmogIndex":5.999999999999999}

print(json.dumps(json.dumps(s)))
```

result:

```
"{\"SmogIndex\": 5.999999999999999, \"AutomaticReadabilityIndex\": 2.7999999999999994, \"SpacheScore\": 1.877, \"GunningFogScore\": 9.099999999999998, \"AgeLevel\": [\" 11 to 12\"], \"Statement\": [\"Nice. Your grade is about six\"]}"
```

So either:

- you're chaining two dumps. The first dump converts the dictionary into string, but dumping a string is also valid, so the string is dumped, quotes, escaped, etc...
- you're dumping a string which looks like a dictionary (`"{12:1,14:2}"`).

(If you're not sure of the type, check `type(s)` before performing the dump)

So when you reload with

```
par = json.loads(s)
```

you get a string, not a dictionary, which explains the error message when using `[]` (since you're trying to pass a key to a string)

Workaround:

use `json.loads(json.loads(s))` to recover your data.

and as a better fix, just use `dumps` once in the serialization process.

Comment: I understand what you have said, but in my code I am using `dumps` only once. Anyway, I thought that if I have string which is formatted like json I should easily convert it to obj using `loads` method

Comment: you're using dumps on something that is already a string then. If it's already a string, just write it directly to file, don't use `json`